# GraphQL query how to pass variables

Tags: graphql

Hi all I have a query where I am trying to get messages from a user with a specific `uuid` or a `role` that matches the users role. I am unsure of how to properly use the `_ilike` or `%` in this instance. I've tried a myriad of combinations yet the role messages never get returned. My query as it sits now and the hook used in the component are below.

I appreciate any feedback.

Here is my query

```
query getUserMessages($userId: String!) {
  messageReceivers(
    where: { _or: [{ userId: { _eq: $userId } }, { message: { roles: { _ilike: "%" } } }] }
  ) {
    messageId
    userId
    message {
      id
      audioLink
      body
      videoLink
      user {
        firstName
        lastName
        photo
        title
        specialty
        profession
        location
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Using the lazyquery hook in component

```js
  const [getUserMessages, { error, called, loading, data }] = useGetUserMessagesLazyQuery()
  const userRole = `%${user.role}%`

  useEffect(() => {
    getUserMessages({
      variables: { userId: user?.id, message: { roles: { _ilike: userRole } } },
    })
  }, [user])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incorrectly passing `userRole` to the query.  To fix it, apply `userId`'s pattern to `userRole`.

1. In the query definition, add `$userRole` in the operation signature (You are currently hardcoding `_ilike` to `%` in the query, but you want set it dynamically as `$userRole`).
2. In the calling function, send the variables correctly `variables: { userId: user?.id, userRole: userRole}`.

The [GraphQL Variable docs](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables) neatly describe how this fits together.

Comment: Thanks @fedonev! I was able to work it out before seeing your answer but have upvoted your answer and marked as the solution though I posted my end solution as well. Thank again!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @fedonev! Though I didn't see your solution you were absolutely correct. I was able to work it out a little differently and I hope this helps someone who's run into the same issue.

By creating the variable `$role` in the query I was able to use the same syntax as was being used by the `userId` variable. If anyone has this issue please feel free to comment I will happily help if I can.

Query

```
query getUserMessages($userId: String!, $role: String = "%") {
  messages(
    where: {
      _or: [{ roles: { _ilike: $role } }, { messageReceivers: { userId: { _eq: $userId } } }]
    }
    order_by: { createdAt: desc }
  ) {
    createdAt
    id
    body
    audioLink
    videoLink
    roles
}
```

Call from in component

```
useEffect(() => {
    getUserMessages({
      variables: { userId: user?.id, role: user?.role },
    })
  }, [user])
```